# How bind search values in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code in my /search/:query route:

```
var param = {
    query: req.query['query']
}

MyModel.find({
        "$or": [
            { 'name': req.param.query },
            { 'age': req.param.query  },
            { 'event': req.param.query },
        ]
    }, function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        else {
            res.render('index', { 
                data: results
            });
        }
    }
);
```

And is good, i can search for pretty much every data that i want, but only individually. What if i want search name + age, can i? Example: 'Leo 22'.

There is any way that mongoose help me with this?

UPDATE:

My problem is:

I have tables lists it titles, this title is the concatenation of 'eventName' and 'eventDate'.

Real examples of this fields:

'Special Event - 20/12/2015'
'Classic Event - 12/03/2015'
'Hot Summer Event - 05/07/2005'

Every week will be create 4 events. In some point, a user will search for an old event, and i believe that the user will search in this format:'EVENT NAME - EVENT DATE'..

So i need a way to bind this values in my controllers.

Comment: We don't do mindreading here, though I admit it would often be useful. At least my Professor X powers aren't working here so please: 1. Clearly explain with examples what you want to achieve. 2. If you have some concept of what type of data is being submitted as "query" then please show it. 3. Don't comment back! Just please take more care asking questions and explaining what you want.

Comment: Just update my answer @NeilLunn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using only one parameter (`req.param.query`) to filter all attributes. That's not mongoose related: you could create distinct parameters for each attribute and pass them along the query string.

For instance:

```
"$or": [
        { 'name': req.param.name },
        { 'age': req.param.age  },
        { 'event': req.param.event },
    ]
```

And your HTTP request will be like this:

http://youraddress/expressRoute?name=Leo&age=22

Comment: great, this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I'm no familiar with `mongoose` but in order to do that, you must have a way to bind your query param to the attribute you want to search. Otherwise, they wouldn't know `Leo` is name and `22` is age.

Ur path would be like `search?name=:name&age=:age&event=:event` and in your code, you will have to process like if the param is not `null`, add and condition to it.

Comment: Oh, I was 20 seconds late. (+1)